# Dynamic compiling curl works, but static curl compiled errors

Tags: c, curl, static-linking

When I compile and run my program dynamically curl works fine, but when compiled as static I get this:

```
$  gcc -static -o main.exe -w main.c `pkg-config --static --cflags libcurl` `pkg-config --static --cflags regex` `pkg-config --static --cflags jansson` `pkg-config --static --cflags sqlite3` `pkg-config --static --cflags iconv` `pkg-config --static --cflags libssl`                     `pkg-config --static --libs libcurl` `pkg-config --static --libs regex` `pkg-config --static --libs jansson` `pkg-config --static --libs sqlite3`  `pkg-config --static --libs iconv` `pkg-config --static --libs libssl` -g && ./main.exe

curl_easy_perform() failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
curl_easy_perform() failed: Couldn't resolve host name
```